# Use the division algorithm to establish that, The cube of any integer is either of the form $9k ,9k + 1, 9k + 8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Use the division algorithm to establish that, The cube of any integer is either of the form $9k ,9k + 1, 9k + 8$.

Let $a$ is an integer, write $a = 9k + r, 0 \le r < 9$  hence $r = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ then $$a^3 =(9k + r)^3 = 9(9k^3 + 3kr(9k +r )) + r^3, 0 \le r³ < 9$$

when $r=0 \to r^3 = 0$
when $r=1 \to r^3 = 1$
when $r=2 \to r^3 = 8$
when $r=3 \to r^3 = 27$

Since $0\le r^3 < 9$ above $8$ values cannot be accepted.  Hence $r^3\in{0,1,8}$. Hence $a^3$ can express in $a^3 = 9k, a^3 = 9k + 1, a^3 = 9k + 8$ forms. Therefore cube of any integer is form $9k, 9k + 1,$ or $9k + 8$.

Is this correct? Are there other solutions?

Comment: Use `$$`'s to write beautiful formulas.

Answer (score 4):

1. $a=3n\Longrightarrow a^3=(3n)^3=9\cdot(3n^3)\equiv0\pmod 9$
2. $a=3n+1\Longrightarrow a^3=(3n)^3+3(3n)^2+3(3n)+1=9\cdot(3n^3+3n^2+n)+1\equiv1\pmod9$
3. $a=3n+2\Longrightarrow a^3=(3n)^3+6(3n)^2+12(3n)+8=9\cdot(3n^3+6n^2+4n)+8\equiv8\pmod9$

Comment: Thank you very much!. I got the idea,

Comment: @Chanukat As Student's answer shows, with this kind of question it's good to use the smallest multiplier that gets you to the solution, which is 3 in this problem. That way, you have fewer values of $r$ that you need to check. Personally, I'd use $a=3k+r$, for $r\in\{0,1,2\}$, so $$a^3=9(3k^3+3k^2r+kr^2) + r^3$$

Comment: @Chanukat BTW, if this answer has helped you, you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/334566) it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a supplementary answer:

You want to be a little careful for why $27$ can be disregarded. Note that if $a=9k+27$ then $a=9(k+3)+0$. So what's really happening is that remainder $27$ can be rewritten to be remainder $0$. For example, consider what happens if you do $6$ instead of $9$.

Write $a=6k+r$ such that $0\leq r <6$. Then $a^3=6k'+r^3$ for some appropriate $k'$.

If $r=0$ then $r^3=0$.

If $r=1$ then $r^3=1$.

If $r=2$ then $r^3=8$.

If $r=3$ then $r^3=27$.

If $r=4$ then $r^3=64$.

If $r=5$ then $r^3=125$.

If I stopped after the first two and said that values above $5$ can be disregarded, then I might incorrectly conclude that the cube of any number can be written as $6k$ or $6k+1$ for some $k$. But in fact $8$ corresponds to remainder $2$ (mod $6$), $27$ to remainder $3$ (mod $6$), and $125$ to remainder $5$ (mod $6$).

So in fact cubes are represented by $6k$, $6k+1$, $6k+2$, $6k+3$, and $6k+5$.

Comment: ,if I apply a = 3k + r instead of a = 9k + r, Does my proof work?

Comment: Yes, if you consider $a$ mod $3$, and then simplify the cube mod $9$, then you get the same information. Of course, this is the idea of Student1058's nice answer.